# Python Scrapy: Skip Xpath if it's not there

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have this code which scrapes a few hundred pages for me. But sometimes the xpath for `a` doesn't exist at all, how can I edit this so the script doesn't stop and keeps running to get the `b` and just give me that for that specific page?

```
`a = response.xpath("//div[@class='headerDiv']/a/@title").extract()[0]
b = response.xpath("//div[@class='headerDiv']/text()").extract()[0].strip()
items['title'] = a + " " + b
yield items`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the result of `extract()`.

```
nodes = response.xpath("//div[@class='headerDiv']/a/@title").extract()
a = nodes[0] if nodes else ""

nodes = response.xpath("//div[@class='headerDiv']/text()").extract()
b = nodes[0].strip() if nodes else ""

items['title'] = a + " " + b
yield items
```

With the good advice of Padraic Cunningham:

```
a = response.xpath("//div[@class='headerDiv']/a/@title").extract_first(default='')
b = response.xpath("//div[@class='headerDiv']/text()").extract_first(default ='').strip() 
items['title'] = (a + " " + b).strip()
yield items
```

Comment: `extract_first(default ='')` but you are going to add a leading space if a does not exist so you need to only concat a to b if a exists or just add b

Comment: `(a + ' ' +b).strip()` will catch when a does not return a match. You also don't want to index extract_first as it returns a string as you would be getting  just the first character

Answer (score 0):

You can use as follow:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False, remove_comments=True)
root = etree.fromstring(data, parser)

#Take Hyperlink as per xpath:
#But Xpath returns list of element so we have to take 0 index of it if it has element

a = root.xpath("//div[@class='headerDiv']/a/@title")
b = response.xpath("//div[@class='headerDiv']/text()")

if a:
    items['title'] = a[0].strip() + " " + b[0].strip() 
else:
    items['title'] = b[0].strip() 

yield items
```